# How to keep a drawn rectangle in the same place as the camera moves around

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I have this application where a rectangle is drawn in the initial frame. I wanted to know if it is possible to make the rectangle a part of the image from the next frame onwards.

For example in my first frame I would draw something like this but a bit darker
https://i.stack.imgur.com/enKCE.jpg

I want it to become a part of the environment, so that the next time my camera accesses that frame I should see a rectangular box. How to do this using OpenCV?

Edit: My algorithm finds and draws the rectangle in the first frame. I'm trying to keep the rectangle in the same place as the camera moves around and the rectangle need not be always on the white board.

Comment: @EdChum I have modified my question

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, you're asking if it's possible. yes it's possible so what's your question? Asking if it can be done can be answered either as a yes or becomes a very broad question as you've not demonstrated what your thoughts on this are, approaches, code, etc..

Comment: Is the rectangle always going to be on a whiteboard? Or can it be drawn anywhere (on any object)...

Comment: Are you trying to keep the rectangle in the same place (on the white board) as the camera moves around? Or are you asking whether you can use opencv to draw rectangles onto the video (not its intended purpose).

Comment: @Ron I'm trying to keep the rectangle in the same place as the camera moves around.

Comment: It looks like what you attempting is some form of object tracking in order to generate a homography and then apply this homography to your rectangle. It depends on what features you want to track, for simple distinct features, simple methods like pearson correlation, harris corner detection can work if for example you tracked something distinct. More complicated methods may involve Surf tracking and optical flow, optical flow by the way will be very slow for large images and without GPU acceleration.

Comment: With [planar tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_tracking), one advantage is that it does not require features as such, rather it detects luminance changes, this is probably the better approach along with optical flow for your situation as the board has very few features. However it can be slow, I think this question is better suited to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision or http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision

Comment: In your sample image you can `track` the planar board and remember the rectangle position within that planar board (it's a "quite easy" task since the board is planar). In general cases you will have to track the camera position and you might need some 3D reconstruction and other scene understanding and you have to define better what means to "keep in the same place" since you mark it in 2D and the camera moves in 3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What what you are trying to achieve is possible, but its going to take some research and work on your part. One possible solution to your problem is to use Optical Flow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) analysis to monitor the apparent motion of objects in your cameras view. You could use the resulting optical flow field to apply a "correction" to the positions of the corners of your rectangle between each frame. Here is a link to the OpenCV documentation for their optical flow functions:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/video.html

If the particular device you are using has a gyroscope, and gps/ins you might also use this data to supplement the optical flow data. Let me know how it goes, sounds like a really fun project!

Answer (score 0):

You need a static rectangle that has nothing to do with what is *in* the image? Just draw a rectangle on every frame you capture.

```
    Rect r = Rect( .. );
    rectangle( imageFromCam, r, Scalar( .. ) );
```

[cv::rectangle( )](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)

[Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect)

Comment: This will not work as I'm interested in the content of the image.